# AutoPostBack ONCE on pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview with a dropdown, with autopostback enabled.

The user can select yes - which postsback and brings up loads more dropdowns, no - which brings up a textbox, and blank - which does nothing.

As the original dropdownbox is databound it displays one of those values but at the moment always acts as if it was blank ie no other controls showing..

Can I make the page do ONE autopostback as soon as it's loaded without any user input to display the correct controls if it's a yes or no as opposed to blank?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Kindly put code in support of your question.

Comment: you could do a __doPostBack(... at the end of pageload, but seems an X/Y problem

Comment: How about setting the values when loading the page? It's difficult to know if this would work without seeing your code, though. You should be able to encapsulate the logic that is called when the DDL posts back into a method, then call that method during page load I would think.

Comment: I didn't think it would work but actually it did work simply placing the c# code block for handling the dropdownchangeevent into the pageload.. cheers

Answer (score 1):

try calling dropdownbox_selectedindexchanged(null,null) after binding in page load. it is just calling selectedindexchanged event programmatically. as far as i know you want to load controls based on dropdown selection when page first load and user haven't changed dropdown value. so this code will call it from code behind.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add this there. As per the rules of stackoverflow, your answer may be deleted if it is too short.

Comment: @MamtaD changed as you suggested